# downloading or displaying BlobProperties from Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How would I go about selecting and downloading or displaying individual entries from the Datastore. Specifically if those entries contain a BlobProperty.

Comment: What's in the blob field? Is it binary data, is it an image, is it a file to download, etc.? Your question is difficult to answer without a lot more information.

Comment: I'm sorry I frogot . I'm storing pdfs . they should be very small

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on what you are currently storing in the BlobProperty. Since it is typically used to store data with an upper size limit of 1 MB, I am assuming that you are storing it for images or even some files, which are under that limit.

In all probability, you might want to either provide a link to the user via your web application to either download the document or if it is an image, you might want to render it yourself in the web application (for e.g. a user's avatar or something).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to download a blob stored in the datastore. First the HTML:

```
<a href="/dynfile/example/Disclaimer.pdf">Disclaimer</a>
```

I use webapp2 and NDB. The server code.

```
class DynLoad(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, parent, cid):

        dyn = ndb.Key('Dynamic', cid, parent=ndb.Key('Examples', parent)).get()                                     
            if dyn:

                self.response.headers[str('ETag')] = str(dyn.modified)
                if 'If-None-Match' in self.request.headers:
                etags = [x.strip()
                         for x in self.request.headers[str('If-None-Match')].split(',')]
                if str(dyn.modified) in etags:
                    self.response.set_status(304)
                    return

            content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(cid)[0]
            self.response.headers[str('Content-Type')] = str(content_type)
            self.response.headers[str('Content-Disposition')] = str('attachment; filename=%s' % cid)
                self.response.out.write(dyn.blob)
        else:
            logging.error('Blob NOT FOUND for : %s parent : %s' % (cid, parent))
```

The webapp2 route:

```
    webapp2.Route(r'/dynload/<parent:[^/]+>/<cid:[^/]+>', handler=DynLoad, name='dynload'),
```